# Low sound quality with Kontakt 5

Tags: fl-studio, sound-quality, kontakt

I'm new to Kontakt, I've downloaded it today. But when I installed my first library (Symphony Series Brass Ensemble), and tried the samples, the sound quality was completely unacceptable. I tried changing the audio settings but it remains as it is... my DAW is FL Studio. I have a "decent" laptop to work on, it runs all the software perfectly fine with 2.5 GB RAM. 
It seems like when I play the notes, Kontakt "tries" to sound in good quality, because when I play a lot of notes at the same time, the quality increses to a high level for a second but then jumps right back to a terrible sound quality... what can this be?

Answer (score 1):

Best guess - 2.5GB RAM... which is barely enough to run the OS these days, let alone a DAW with a massive sample playback engine on top.

When manufacturers say 'minimum spec', that's really what they mean... absolute minimum to get it to work at all.

Ref: https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/samplers/kontakt-5-player/specifications/